# Is the Laplacian operator closed?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, laplacian

I am trying to verify that the Laplacian operator is closed on $D(-\Delta)$. For this I do the following

Let $-\Delta:D(-\Delta)\subset L^2\to L^2$ where $D(\Delta):=\left\{u\in L^2:-\Delta u\in L^2\right\}$

Let $\left\{u_n\right\}\subset D(-\Delta)$ with $u_n\to u$ in $D(-\Delta)$ and $-\Delta u_n\to v$ in $L^2$. I want proves that $u\in D(-\Delta)$ and $-\Delta u_n\to -\Delta u$ in $L^2$.

\begin{align}
|-\Delta u|_{2}&\leq |-\Delta u_n-\Delta u|_2+|-\Delta u_n|_2\\
&=|-\Delta (u_n-u)|_{2}+|-\Delta u_n|_{2}\\
&\leq |-\Delta| |u_n-u|_{2}+|-\Delta u_n|_{2}\\
&\to c
\end{align}
because $-\Delta u_n\to v\text{ in } L^2\Rightarrow |-\Delta u_n|\leq c$, $n\to \infty$.
Therefore $u\in D(-\Delta)$.

By the other hand, $|-\Delta u_n-\Delta u|_{2}\leq |-\Delta| |u_n-u|_{2}\to 0$ therefore $-\Delta u_n\to -\Delta u$ in $L^2.$

The problem is that in the above, I used that $|-\Delta (u_n-u)|_{2}\leq |-\Delta| |u_n-u|_{2}$ but I don't know if that is true.

**Actualization 1**.
Let $H^2:=\left\{u\in L^2: (Id-\Delta)u\in L^2\right\}$ with the norm $|u|_{H^2}=|(Id-\Delta)u|_{2}$ and $D(-\Delta)=\left\{u\in L^2: -\Delta u \in L^2\right\}$.

**Affirmation 1**. $D(-\Delta)=H^2$

**Affirmation 2**. $-\Delta:D(-\Delta)\subset L^2\to L^2$ is closed in $H^2$

Proof: Let $\left\{u_n\right\}\subset D(-\Delta)$ with $u_n\xrightarrow[ ]{H^2}u$ and $-\Delta u_n\xrightarrow[]{L^2} v$ then
\begin{align}
|u|_{H^2}^{2}&\leq |u_n-u|_{H^2}^2+|u_n|_{H^2}^2\\
&\leq |u_n-u|_{H^2}^2+c\to c
\end{align}
In the above use the following: $u_n\xrightarrow[ ]{H^2}u$ then exists $c>0$ such that for all $n$, $|u_n|_{H^2}\leq c$? is this true?

Moreover,
\begin{align}
|-\Delta u_n-(-\Delta u)|_{2}&=|-\Delta(u_n-u)|_{2}\\
&\leq |u_n-u|_{H^2}\to 0
\end{align}

Therefore, $-\Delta$ is closed in $H^{2}$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: $u_n\xrightarrow[ ]{H^2}u$ then exists $c>0$ such that for all $n$, $|u_n|_{H^2}\leq c$? is this true?